# Moq Setup for method with expression<Func<t,bool>> argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to mock the following repository method

```
IEnumerable<T> All(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
```

below mock setup works fine

```
repository.Setup(repo => repo.All(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<UserLog, bool>>>())).Returns(userLogs);
```

however, when I want to setup with a specific expression, it does not work. When called, method "All" doesn't return the userlogs object as specified.

```
repository.Setup(repo => repo.All(v=>v.UserId==userId)).Returns(userLogs);
```

I've also tried the following. I know its ugly but I got curious if it would work, and it did.

```
repository.Setup(ulr => 
                        ulr.All(It.Is<Expression<Func<UserLog, bool>>>(e => 
                        e.Compile().Invoke(new UserLog { UserId = userId }))))
.Returns(userLogs);
```

However, weirdly enough, moving that cumbersome expression into a seperate variable and passing it in instead, did not work. like below

```
var itis = It.Is<Expression<Func<UserLog, bool>>>(e => e.Compile().Invoke(new UserLog { UserId = userId }));
repository.Setup(ulr => ulr.All(itis)).Returns(userLogs);
```

The mocked method is being called as follows;

```
repository.All(u=>u.UserId==userId);
```

What I want to do is to mock a method for a specific Expression>.

I can't figure this one out, would love some help.

Thanks.

Comment: `it does not work`, what does that mean? Does it give any error? What unexpected behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Well the setup doesn't work. The return function is not called as expected

Comment: Can you add an example of what a *call* to the mocked method looks like please?

Comment: repository.All(u=>u.UserId==userId); this is how the mocked method is being called

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the passed expression from the mock and apply it to the fake results using linq

```
repository
.Setup(_ => _.All(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<UserLog, bool>>>()))
.Returns((Expression<Func<UserLog, bool>> arg) => userLogs.Where(arg.Compile()));
```

When the mocked member is called with something like this, for example

```
var repo = repository.Object;
var result = repo.All(user => user.UserId == userId);
```

the `user => user.UserId == userId` expression passed to the repo will be invoked  in the mock setup, assuming `userLogs` is of type `IEnumerable<UserLog>`

Comment: this doesnt really apply well to my case. UserLog collection is created through AutoFixture and calling .Where on it won't yield the expected result. I could ofcouse modify my test method to suit this but I'd rather not, if there is a simpler solution.
I feel like setting up the method with the expression  (u)=>u.UserId == userId) should work. The second case I've explained is even weirder.

Comment: @Rudithus so then can you update the original post so that all the necessary details are known to be able to reproduce the problem. There was no mention of using a fixture in the original post.

Comment: I don't think it's really related, since my question is about setting up the mock method. What I'm looking for is a way to setup the method call for a specific expression statement.